# Python, tkinter how to make the window click-through Linux

Tags: python, tkinter

I have seen the post about how to do it on Windows, but i need a Linux version. Is there any way? (Yes, i Googled before i came here)
What i basically want to do is to open a maximized transparent click through window, to mainly use it as a "dark reader"
here my tiny code :)

```
from tkinter import * 
win = Tk()
win.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()))
win.wait_visibility(win)
win.configure(bg="black")
win.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried this on Linux?

Comment: Yes, i tried it now. And like expected, it didnt work.

Comment: Setting `alpha` option does not make the window *click-through*.  Try using `transparentcolor` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I know that.. That option makes my window transparent. But i also want click though.

Comment: The transparent part of the window should be click-through.

Comment: @acw1668 i get this error: bad attribute "-transparentcolor": must be -alpha, -topmost, -zoomed, -fullscreen, or -type
My code: window.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "black")

Comment: Sorry that `transparentcolor` option is for Windows only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to answer my question, after i got the solution. Thanks to Andrew Hernandez, i checked out PyQT5 and with that i could make what i needed. Here the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys

DR = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = QtWidgets.QWidget()

screen = DR.primaryScreen()
size = screen.size()
w = size.width()
h = size.height()

win.resize(w, h)
win.setWindowTitle("Dark Reader")
win.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)
win.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
win.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
win.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
win.showMaximized()
sys.exit(DR.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simplified Explication

@Z3r0ut, Your probably using `python 2.x` because that is what most Linux distributions use. If you want to run the code, you can simple start with this argument `python %FILENAME%.py`.

```py
!/usr/bin/python
-*- encoding: utf8 -*-
try:
   import Tkinter as tk
   from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:

win = Tk()
win.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (win.winfo_screenwidth(), win.winfo_screenheight()))
win.wait_visibility(win)
win.configure(bg="black")
win.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)

win.mainloop()
```

### Detailed Explication

These effects depend on your operating system, therefore you can't make Linux re-create these effects like `windows 10/11`. For example, `shader.dll` is used for shaders, `dynamic.dll` is used for screen smoothing, `fix.dll` is used for styling windows. Every one, can be found on `regedit`.

It can be made, but you need third-party API's or links for your file. If you're trying to make it, I would recommend you using c/c++ for it!

Comment: wtf? What has this answer to do with my question? first, im using Python 3.10.4, thats what my disto, garuda linux comes with.
And i dont want to recreate windows stuff.. I just want to make my transparent window also click through. My above code works just fine. I just want click through in it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with Tkinter because it's an old library, try using qt5